# Parse error on input ‘->’

Tags: haskell

I was doing an exercize from the Haskellwiki (99 questions) and I am getting "exercize.hs:1:12: parse error on input ‘->’ ":

```
myLast [a] -> a
myLast [] = error "Empty list has no last element"
myLast [x] = x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
```

I am using Notepad++ on a Win8.1, the compiler is GHCi. I rewrote it many times and I can't see a mistake.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `::`

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
```